# Swift - Optimizing working with very long arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, optimization

I have some places in my code which looks like this:

```
var i = 0
for c in vertexStates[0] {
            //this operation is costy (encapsulates 4 linear interpolation inside)
            currentVertexes.append(vertexStates[1][i++].interpolateTo(c, alpha: factor))
}
```

And I know that there is more than 1000 vertexes in vertexStates[index] array for sure (maybe up to 3000). What are the best practices for optimizing (vectorizing) such operations? Should figure out how to do it in some threads? Will profits from using multi-threading outweight over head? Maybe there are other ways of doing such operations faster?

I need general approach on how to optimize such operations (in my case which produces array from two other arrays and order is important for me), no matter if 3000 counts as long or not. My iPhone 6 Plus CPU is loaded by 65% during this operations, so I can predict 4s will show very poor results, even though I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: Just want to be mildly obnoxious and repeat the same advice in the answer. The best practice and the most general strategy here is to measure. If there's anything holding the world in general back from achieving more efficient code, it's this general allergy to profilers. Even someone with a very shallow understanding of computer architecture can do far better than even the most seasoned assembly experts who still feel the need to drive their optimizations based on hunches rather than proper measurements. How to optimize will tend to take care of itself once you figure out what to optimize.

Answer (score 2):

100 isn't very long. 300 isn't very long. 100,000 is where we can start arguing whether something is very long.

Did you measure how long things take? What is the slowest device where your code could run? If you run on iOS 7, how well does it run on an iPhone 4? If you run on iOS 8 or 9 only, how well does it run on 4s or iPad 2?

The first step is measuring. Post with results.

Comment: Well, it isn't that long, but it still slows down my game. I don't have old devices, but my iPhone 6 Plus CPU is loaded by 65%, meaning 4s will show very poor results. And I need general approach on how to optimize long for loops which produces another array.

Comment: I gave you the advice: Measure. I would _bet_ that this line of code is not the problem. Unless you call it a million times. Picking two lines of code and deciding that they need to be optimised is a mug's game.

Comment: Was about to post an answer but it'd be quite redundant with this one. 1,000-3,000 vertices should hardly be bottlenecky, and 4 lerps hardly constitutes as "costly" (especially with such a small input size). Measuring these things is the first step -- parallelization, cache-related optimizations, and SIMD come after measuring for these kinds of linear complexity algorithms. First thing to figure out is exactly what to optimize in this context -- the how part comes after.